# dwr comet approach

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, comet, dwr

from http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/reverse-ajax/index.html  , it stated it supports polling, comet,piggyback. does that mean when we implement this approach, we can change to this 3 options in configuration without changing codes? what does dwr implement different from atmosphere api? dwr can be used on all j2ee containers also right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used both,

You should prepare client side codes, made serious thread management and data serialization if you choose atmosphere.

There are less server options on DWR side. :(

There is no new release for DWR last ~9 months.. :(